# Thinkpad T440 trackpad multitouch not working

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch

I am using a Thinkpad T440s with the new trackpad that has physical buttons.

I ran into the issue that the physical buttons (which are recognized as a seperate PS/2 device) do not function. After a lot of research, i found that executing `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps` makes the buttons work properly.

However, it also causes the touchpad not to work with multitouch scrolling. Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Here is the output from xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`uname -r` returns `3.16.0-36-generic`.

I found that after adding `Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"` to the catchall section of my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` the left and right mouse buttons above the touchpad now scroll up and down. This does not change if i use modprobe to change the protocol to imps.

Here's my 50-synaptics.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
            Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on
# non-synaptics clickpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
#       To disable the bottom edge area so the buttons only work as buttons,
#       not for movement, set the AreaBottomEdge
#       Option "AreaBottomEdge" "82%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

UPDATE:

It seems that when I reboot my system, the touchpad (with mulititouch) works fine, and synclient returns the parameters. The buttons do not work. As soon as I use `modprobe -r psmouse` and `modprobe psmouse proto=imps` the buttons work, but the touchpad no longer works with multitouch and synclient returns `unable to find a synaptics device`.
Is there a way to just set the buttons to use the imps protocol?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` command. And remove Mint from your question or it will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, I added the output from `xinput`. It seems like the extra buttons are recognized as a keyboard. That raises the question why I need to use psmouse in order for them to function.

Comment: Psmouse contains the touchpad driver. Please also add output of `uname -r`. These `extra buttons` are not related to touchpad.

Comment: I have added `uname -r` as well as `50-synaptics.conf`, since that also seems to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade kernel. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

Comment: Upgrading to `3.19.0-25` causes the buttons to work properly on boot, but multitouch won't function. Synclient doesn't recognize the touchpad.

Comment: Try to boot with Ubuntu 15.04 Live USB. It seems to work with this touchpad.

Comment: I tried the live USB, which works. Now instead of reinstalling I'd like to see how I can fix my existing installation. What I just noticed is that in the login screen the mouse works fine but as soon as I log in the mouse pointer slows down. Is there a way to see the things that happen when I log in?

Comment: The only reason why it does not work on 14.04 with 3.19 kernel and does on 15.04 is systemd in 15.04. But how can it affect touchpad is a mystery.